# r.water.outlet returning blank raster

Tags: grass-gis

I am trying to delineate a watershed using r.water.outlet.

I have created a flow direction raster using r.watershed (threshold = 50) (cell size is 300m).

I use this flow direction raster in r.water.outlet
I then specify EXACT coordinates of a location on a stream network, also created using r.watershed (in wgs84 - crs that the grass porject is in).

a blank 'black' raster is returned. The style tab in properties has max:1. min:1 (when compute min max).

I have re-run the analysis several times with different output from r.watershed (i.e. using different thresholds) - but has the same result.

Comment: Please check if your http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Computational_region is set correctly to the raster map (or subregion of interest on the map).